# Spark Shell how to use breeze-viz

Tags: shell, plot, apache-spark, breeze

I use spark shell and I want to use

```
import breeze.plot._
```

Attach details

I call spark-shell with the jars

```
[cloudera@quickstart lib]$ spark-shell --jars /home/cloudera/ExamplesAnalytics/ExamplesOfAnalytics/lib/breeze_2.10-0.9.jar 
/home/cloudera/ExamplesAnalytics/ExamplesOfAnalytics/lib/gs-core-1.2.jar
/home/cloudera/ExamplesAnalytics/ExamplesOfAnalytics/lib/jcommon-1.0.16.jar 
/home/cloudera/ExamplesAnalytics/ExamplesOfAnalytics/lib/pherd-1.0.jarn 
/home/cloudera/ExamplesAnalytics/ExamplesOfAnalytics/lib/gs-ui-1.2.jar
/home/cloudera/ExamplesAnalytics/ExamplesOfAnalytics/lib/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar 
/home/cloudera/ExamplesAnalytics/ExamplesOfAnalytics/lib/breeze-viz_2.10-0.9.jar
```

I do the following imports

```
scala> import breeze.linalg._
import breeze.linalg._ 

scala> import breeze.plot._
<console>:22: error: object plot is not a member of package breeze
   import breeze.plot._
                 ^

scala>
```

How do I have to import breeze.plot._ from spark shell

Answer (score 1):

Download from central (JAR), Breeze Viz » 0.12 [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalanlp/breeze-viz_2.10/0.12) and Breeze » 0.12 [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalanlp/breeze_2.10/0.12), after go to directory lib of ExamplesAnalytics and delete breeze-viz_2.10-0.9.jar and breeze_2.10-0.9.jar. Finally, copy and paste the two .jar download in the folder lib.

spark-shell --jars lib/gs-core-1.2.jar,lib/gs-ui-1.2.jar,lib/jcommon-1.0.16.jar,lib/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar,lib/breeze_2.10-0.12.jar,lib/breeze-viz_2.10-0.12.jar,lib/pherd-1.0.jar